# Getting the bounds/frame for UICollectionview at the right time

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uicollectionview

I am writing an app (IOS, Objective-C) which starts with a Collectionview containing buttons, depending on the button i will push the next CollectionViewcontroller or TableviewController to present data.

I am using the function listed below to adapt the size for the cells to the screen (especially when turned from portrait to landscape etc.)

I have the following problem.

When I push a tableviewcontroller from this collectionview and return to the collectionview, the calculation is done correctly and the collectionview looks like it should.

But when returning from another collectionview the calculation is wrong (i.e. the width is far too high), currently testing on a Iphone 5s and the width ist set to something below 400 but after returning from another collectionview the width of the whole view is logged with 560.

So how would it be possible to get the right bounds / frame for my Collectionview ?

I should also mention that I am using sizeclass "Any/Any" and that my collectionviewController is derived from UICollectionviewController in order to accomodate a AdbannerView (embedded the collectionview in another view)

Any help would be highly appreciated, snippet below was taken from some blog and works really good but only when there is not another Collectionview in the stack.

```
    - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
     sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WNCOllectionviewcell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(_WNCollectionView.bounds)*0.4, CGRectGetHeight(cell.frame));
   CGFloat desiredHeight = (CGRectGetHeight(_WNCollectionView.bounds) / _collectionImages.count) * 1.45;
    NSLog (@"Height %.2f", CGRectGetHeight(_WNCollectionView.frame));
    NSLog(@"Width %.2f",CGRectGetWidth(_WNCollectionView.frame));
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.bounds)*0.4, desiredHeight);

    }
```

Declaration of CollectionViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@import iAd;

@interface WNCollectionViewController : UIViewController      <UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, ADBannerViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *WNCollectionView;
@end
```

Comment: Are you sure `collectionView` and `_WNCollectionView` are the same instance? If not, you're printing the wrong value

Comment: added declaration... of CollectionViewController for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by myself and this problem was not solvable for any good-willing reader so please accept my apologies.

In my setup i have CollectionViewController A which calls CollectionViewController B. Both have NavigationControllers. I connected the output of B erroneously directy with the CollectionViewController A and not with A's Navigationcontroller which yielded all funny results. Connecting it the right way (via navigationcontroller) did the job.